# Python printing text next line

Tags: python

I have a text in file text.txt:

```
Tomatoes are red.
Apples are green.
```

And script is

```
i= 1
file = open("text.txt","r")
for list in file:
    i += 1
    print(str(i) + ".",list , len(list))
file.close()
```

Now the problem is that it puts the number in another line than all other.
Help :)

Comment: Use `enumerate` to keep track of an index, don't do it yourself. However, I assume that this is a tutorial excercise or something similar and as such I would urge you to just keep trying and if your still stuck after a while (like 1-2 hours) do feel free to ask here but show us what you have tried, what it did and why that doesn't match with what you were expecting.

Comment: Please do *not* call variables to builtin names like `list`, `set`, `dict`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The line (called `list` for some reason) ends with a newline `\n`. `strip` that newline (and any other surrounding whitespace) and it works fine. Also, you can use `with` to open and close the file, and enumerate to keep track of the line number. And please don't use type names like `file` or `list` for variables, as it shadows the actual types.

```
with open("text.txt","r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line.strip()
        print("{}. {} {}".format(i, line, len(line)))
```

Comment: print("{}. {} {}".format(i+1, line, len(line)))   //increment i by 1

Comment: @AbhishekChandel Good catch, or using `enumerate(f, start=1)`, although it seems that OP even starts with `i` being `2` for the first line, but that's probably a mistake.